# Google Sheets Query ImportRange where Col = Column(NamedRange)

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

```
=QUERY( IMPORTRANGE( "https://URL", "Name Of Sheet!1:999" ), "SELECT * WHERE Col" & COLUMN(namedRange) & "'is not null",0 )
```

This spits out the error of:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "Col1 "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
```

I know part of the solution is working with the "&" symbol to join certain blocks of quotes. The biggest challenge is putting the right quotation marks in the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id", "Name Of Sheet!1:999")}, 
 "where Col"&COLUMN(namedRange)&" is not null", 0)
```

`select *` is not needed if you want all columns

`https://URL` you dont need it either, just put there ID number of the sheet

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Now here's the thing: The namedRange Column is a column with dates. I want to grab columns where the dates are either not blank or equal to a "word" (any string or characters that aren't numbers). The "is Not Null" solution only gives me dates but no strings. I know this isn't relevant to the question but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @WilliamToscano can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I would have to make a totally separate copy as this is a sheet from work. But really the column is exactly as described. They are dates formatted as Date()s. Some of the cells are blank ("") and some of the cells are strings ("Unknown") and one of them is the header row ("Program Entrance Date")

Comment: @WilliamToscano hard to guess like this... try: `=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("id", "Name Of Sheet!1:999")), 
 "where Col"&COLUMN(namedRange)&" is not null", 0))`

Comment: WOW! That worked!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the named range is called TEST

```
"select Col" & COLUMN(TEST) & " where Col" & COLUMN(TEST) & " is not null "
```

or

```
"select * where Col" & COLUMN(TEST) & " is not null "
```

you have omitted WHERE syntax